# Does google index and view the text via OCR on images?

Tags: seo, images

I have a business with a google places address.

Now I need that same business address for another one of my websites.

I don't want to use the same text address for new website as this will dilute the Google places listing, causing duplicate issues and problems with citations.

So I'm thinking of using a screen capture of the address and use it for other website/business.

Will Google still be able to read the address on the image?

If so, can I set image to nofollow, no index, so google can't even see it, only humans?

Comment: See this related question:  [Does Google OCR and index text in the images?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76014/does-google-ocr-and-index-text-in-the-images?rq=1), which has the opposite goal (to get images indexed), but contains relevant answers as to whether Google indexes text in images.

Comment: You can achieve your goal using the answers to this question: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)  They don't specifically use images, they use iframes or AJAX, but the same technique would apply.